# Show popup when hover over a cell - without javascript

Tags: html, css

I want to show the popup when I hover over a cell

```
.cell:hover + .popup {
  display: block;
}
```

But this is not working. It is only working when I hover over the hole table. Can you explain me why? This is strange for me because both are classes. I do not want to use javascript.

```css
.table{
    margin:auto;
    display:table;
    width:800px;
    background-color:lightblue;
    border-collapse:collapse;
}
            
.row
{
    display:table-row;
}
            
.cell
{
    display:table-cell;
    height: 20px;
    padding: 4px;
    border:1px solid black;
}
            
.cell:hover {
    background-color: #ff0000;
}
            
.popup {
    display: none;
}
            
.table:hover + .popup {
    display: block;
}
```

```html
<div class="table">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="cell">1</div>
    <div class="cell">2</div>
    <div class="cell">3</div>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="popup">Stuff shown on hover</div>
```

Comment: Can you please clarify what's not working? When I try it, it shows the text when I hover over each cell.

Comment: if i change         .table:hover + .popup {
            display: block;
        } to         .cell:hover + .popup {
            display: block;
        } it does not work anymore

Answer (score 1):

You're using the [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors), `+`. Since `.popup` is not a sibling of any `.cell`, nothing will happen.

Now, your other rule, `.table:hover + .popup` works because the popup element is a sibling of your table. If you want the cell hover to work *without changing your HTML*, you'll have to use JavaScript - [there are no parent selectors in CSS](https://css-tricks.com/parent-selectors-in-css/).

Comment: @seeberg To do it without JavaScript, you could move the `popup` div inside the `row` div, so that it is a sibling of `cell`, then use CSS to position the popup wherever you want it on the screen.

Comment: @freginold absolutely true, but two things: 1) that changes his HTML structure, and 2) it seems semantically strange to place a popup as a sibling of a "cell-in-a-row" as it's not technically a cell. Not that seeburg _couldn't_ do it...

Comment: Agreed... just offering it as an alternative since he said he didn't want to use JS.

Answer (score 0):

@chazsolo is right about the sibling selector.  However, you can still do it without JavaScript by moving the `.popup` class `div` inside the `.row` class `div` so that it IS a sibling of the `.cell` elements, then use CSS to position the popup wherever you want it on the screen.  For example, something like:

```
.popup {
  display: none;
  position: fixed;
  top: 30%;
}
```

As @chazsolo suggested, you would also need to switch from using the `+` sibling selector to using the `~` sibling selector, so the popup can be activated by hovering over any of the `.cell` elements.

Comment: I would also recommend, if following this approach, that you use the **general sibling** selector, `~`, otherwise there would need to be a popup div after every cell. This would be for the `.cell:hover ~ .popup` rule.